# same code,different answers on windows and ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, strftime

I have a code which is like

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1600162806273/1000).strftime('%H')
```

output on windows interactive python console:

```
'15'
```

output on ubuntu interactive python console:

```
'09'
```

Can somebody please help with this.

Comment: I get 10 :-)  Do these machines have different default timezones?  Try `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(...)`

Comment: thanks @snakecharmerb...it worked...